# Block as block's argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm implementing a library in Objective-C which tries to rely on blocks and reduce the use of delegate calls.

This lib will prompt the app for user credentials when needed and the app should provide them invoking a block. Since the credentials are going to be checked by the library, I want the app to provide back another block to get the notified whether the credentials were correct. By that I can keep the UI showing a HUD until I get a response.

I provide a protocol for the main app to implement:

```
@protocol LibProtocol <NSObject>
- (void) needsUserCredentials:(void (^)(NSString *username,
                                    NSString *password,
                                    void (^authResult)(Result result, NSError *error) ))gotCredentials;
@end
```

The app should implement the protocol as follows:

```
- (void) needsUserCredentials:(void (^)(NSString *username,
                                    NSString *password,
                                    void (^)(Result result, NSError *error) ))gotCredentials{
    // get credentials from UI
    gotCredentials(@"username",@"password", ^(Result result, NSError *error){
    if(result == ResultAuthorized) NSLog(@"ResultAuthorized");
    else NSLog(@"ResultDenied"); 
});
```

}

At the library the method is used as follows:

```
[self.delegate needsUserCredentials:^(NSString *username,
                                      NSString *password,
                                      void (^)(Result result, NSError *error)) {
    if([authorizeUser:username password:password]) authResult(AuthResultAuthorized)
    else authResult(AuthResultDenied)    
})];
```

That way I should only need one delegate call the further communication is going to be using blocks.

The problem is that I cannot get the correct syntax for the `authResult` block, the block passed as argument in gotCredentials. I tried many combinations but most of the time I get Xcode's warnings and when I can provide an error-free syntax it crashes when run on simulador/device.

Anybody knows the syntax I should use for the authResult block?

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with function pointers and blocks, it's often a good idea to use typedefs to simplify the syntax and make the code more readable.

For example:

```
typedef void (^UserResponseBlock)(Result result, NSError* error);

typedef void (^UserRequestBlock)(NSString* username, 
                                 NSString* password, 
                                 UserResponseBlock authResult);
```

You now have two types, `UserResponseBlock` and `UserRequestBlock` that can be used just like any other type:

```
- (void)needsUserCredentials:(UserRequestBlock)gotCredentials
{
    gotCredentials(@"username", @"password", ^(Result result, NSError* error) {
        if (result == ResultAuthorized)
        {
            NSLog(@"Result Authorized");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Result Denied");
        }
    });
}
```